# Pick items where the last insert in the DB is older than X days

Tags: mysql

I have a table, let's call it `user_connections`, this table is something similar to the example below:
`user_connections`:

```
| id | location_id | user_id |        ip       |  created_at         |
| 1  |       3     |     2   | 231.134.123.123 | 2019-06-15 10:00:00 |
| 2  |       7     |     5   | 231.134.123.123 | 2019-06-17 12:32:43 |
| 3  |       8     |     9   | 231.134.123.123 | 2019-06-18 17:23:45 |
```

What I want is: Given a set of `location_id`, all `user_connections` in this set that have not had any connection in the last 3 days

I tried to group by `location_id` and restrict only to entries older than `"NOW () - 3 Days"`, but I could not make the logic to only get the entries that have the highest possible `ID` (Last Entries)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include the related section of code. How are you getting your "created at" information? Timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

Throw a rank on your query, partition by location id, order by create date. Either direct or within a nested query, pluck your highest rank.

Answer (score 0):

Test this one

```
SELECT 
    MAX(id), location_id, user_id, ip, created_at
FROM
    user_connections
WHERE
    created_at > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY
GROUP BY location_id
ORDER BY id ASC
```